# How to add my products to the open space next to image the image is on the left hand side but I want the products to display on the right hand

Tags: flutter, web

```
child: new Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                child: new Flexible(
                    child: new GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 3),
                  itemCount: storeItems.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return new Card(
                      child: new Stack(
                        alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Text(storeItems[index].itemName),
                              new Text('R${storeItems[index].itemPrice}'),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

[look at x products I want them on the right side of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8FsB.png)

If u look at the line 80 u will see from the flexible im not sure what to do

Comment: I have tryed with the row and container and column but is not working for me

Comment: Is there no one out there that can please help me to solve the problem?????